# kubernetes nginx ingress with proxy protocol ended up with broken header

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, real-ip, proxy-protocol

I try to setup nginx ingress (nodeport) on google container with proxy protocol so that the real ip can be forwarded to backend service, but ended up with broken header.

```
2017/02/05 13:48:52 [error] 18#18: *2 broken header: "�����~��]H�k��m[|����I��iv.�{y��Z �嵦v�Ȭq���2Iu4P�z;�    o$�s����"���+�/�,�0̨̩����/" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 10.50.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

If without the proxy protocol, thing works well. According to the https://blog.mythic-beasts.com/2016/05/09/proxy-protocol-nginx-broken-header/ this is due to the protocol v2 is used (binary), but nginx only can speak v1. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

GKE: With kubernetes v1.6+ source ip is preserved by default and can be found in headers under `x-real-ip` without setting any extra nginx config.

AWS: Source ip can be preserved by adding this to the annotations

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: '*'
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
```

Checkout this link 
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/examples/aws/nginx

Comment: Newer link that explains the annotation: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/blob/main/docs/guide/service/nlb.md#protocols

Comment: At last! That solved it for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem myself. For me, I wasn't behind a load balancer (other than my nginx ingress), so I did not actually need `proxy-protocol` set.

However, I was getting `127.0.0.1` as the client ip still. The trick is that there was a bug in the version of the nginx ingress I was using (0.9.0-beta.5). Updating my container image to `gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.8` fixed the issue and I received the proper `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Note that the higher versions (up to beta.11 at the time of writing this) had the issue remaining, so I've stayed on beta.8 for the time being.

You can see the versions available at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL/nginx-ingress-controller.

If you are wanting to look at the configuration options available, check out https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/nginx.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem myself and this was the thing that finally made it work. Updating to version beta.8 of the nginx controller.

In case some people using AWS want to learn from my mistakes, don't go through manual configuration of the load balancer through the aws cli. The above mentioned service annotation does it all for you. I could have saved myself a lot of headache if I had realized that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20356727)

Comment: I guess my answer should have been a comment on Josh's answer. Just wanted to help people who were spending unnecessary time on the AWS cli. Maybe this was not needed, so feel free to delete.